# login cakephp 2.3 static form

Tags: cakephp

I have an html form inside the default layout of cakephp.
I'm new in cake an it's documentation is... well, you know.

My question is if it's possible to set the action for that form to something like "Users/login" and the redirect to the preview page. The Auth component documentation isn't useful either so I'd appreciate if some one of you gives to me some light.

Thanks

Comment: People don't go thoroughly with the documentation and start blaming it. As you can see all answers have an reference to OFFICIAL DOCUMENTATION. The cookbook has everything you need to know. We all have learnt from the official documentation, it has everything.

Comment: really, have you seen the docs for codeigniter?

Comment: have u seen the documentation for MVC3 of asp.net, django for python ? hehe, I was just being rhetorical. But my point is, if you go on to compare, there will always be a better thing. I would only care abt if my concerns are answered or not, "They are !" n btw Cake has very good explanations and docs, it lags examples like other frameworks. Most ppl just copy and paste them, I am not sure if this is what you are referring as "Good Documentation"

Comment: well, you're right my friend :). FYI I changed the designs just to use the fw the right way haha

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [FormHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html) to build the form? If you are, you can specify the form's action in the create method:

```
$this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login'));
```

You can then handle the redirection in your controller's login action. Most likely with: `$this->redirect()`.

[http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::redirect](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3aredirect)

You might find this tutorial helpful with regards to the Auth component:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using the form helper. but I think I'm gonna change the design to avoid this kind of tricks and do the thinks the right way

Comment: by the way. I could do it using my experience in php and other frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

To set the action:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-create

check the option **action**. Should be something like:

```
$this->Form->create('User',array('action'=>array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login')));
```

or maybe you could put directly (not recomended) `'/Users/login'`

Now... For the redirection, check this:

[http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent::$loginRedirect](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent%3a%3a%24loginRedirect)

> **AuthComponent::$loginRedirect**
>
> The URL (defined as a string or array) to the controller action users
>   should be redirected to after logging in. This value will be ignored
>   if the user has an Auth.redirect value in their session.

Cake stores the page you're trying to access in the session, if that page is not public. I'm not really sure if it also stores the url of the page if that page is public, you'd have to test it. But if it doesn't, you could write a few lines on the AppController to make it work.. it should be something like:

```
if current_page is public and current_page is not login or logout page:
    $this->Session->write('Auth.redirect',$this->here);
```

to check if a page is public you'll need to see the Request object, there's a [prefix](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) somewhere on the $params.

Hope this helps... dont give up on the doc ^^...

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using the form helper. but I think I'm gonna change the design to avoid this kind of tricks and do the thinks the right way